# Concrete Syntax - Connector on relation field

Tags: lightning-workbench, f-alloy

I have the following Signature:

```
abstract sig Node{
arc: set Node}
```

Is it possible in a way to specify the arc relation as a Connector in the concrete syntax relation?

```
sig P extends Node{token:Int}{tokens>=0}
```

It could also help me for the case above, the tokens field.

Best,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In F-Alloy, you can map a relation to a signature by defining a mapping from a pair of signatures (typing the relation) to the target signature. 
This means that any combination of atoms in this pair of signatures are to be mapped to a new atom typed by the target signature.

In order to enforce the combinations for which an atom is created to be the ones of the relation you want to represent, you need to write a specific constraint in the guard predicate.

For your example, you would thus have the mapping:

```
mapArc: Node -> Node -> CONNECTOR
```

and the following guard:

```
pred guard_mapArc(n1:Node,n2:Node){
  // the image of n1 via the arc relation is n2
}
```

Also don't forget that the value predicate should keep a reference of the combinations of atoms.

```
pred value_mapArc(n1:Node,n2:Node,c:CONNECTOR){
  // state properties of c in function of the given n1 and n2
}
```

Hope it helps